# CXF Soap request/response

Tags: cxf, interceptor

i have two interceptor(AbstractSoapInterceptor) that handle in and out messsage.
I would to correlate this message in some way, but don't now how.
I think that there is an information on who do the request into SOAP message response but i can't found it.

Can someone help me?

Tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF will handle that for you.  The message has a "getExchange()" method on it that holds the exchange that would be common for both the request and the response.   Any data that you need to hold between the in and out can be stored/retrieved there.